# Is there advantage to use Visual Studio 2017 instead of VS2013 to interface my VC++ DLL to my VB.NET windows forms app?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

Should I stick with Visual Studio 2013 Pro or use latest Visual Studio 2017 Pro to interface my Visual-C++ DLL to my Visual Basic .NET windows forms app GUI?

I will try P/Invoke 'wrap' the VC++ DLL for the VB app.

Comment: This has been feature-complete and stable for the past 12 years.  So unlike VS2017.  Flip a coin, with some luck it lands on "VS2008".

Comment: I went with VS2017 and all worked well...  so far...  haven't shipped yet...  8-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Visual C++ 2013 doesn't support some new features introduced in C++11/14/17.

For example, following code works fine in VC++2017 but doesn't work in VC++2013:

```
class A
{
public:
    int n;
};
cout << sizeof(A::n) << endl;
```

The compiler error on VC++2013 is:

*error C2070: 'unknown': illegal sizeof operand*